# tabla con id con autoincremento que empieza en 0

Tags: mysql, id, autoincremento

En la BD mysql, estoy intentando crear una tabla donde la primary_key es el id con autoincremento pero por requerimientos de la app necesito que empiece en 0. He usado el siguiente código, pero empieza en 1.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE libro (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    titulo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    f_publicacion DATE NOT NULL,
    id_autor INT(6) UNSIGNED,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_autor) REFERENCES autor(id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=0";
```

Comment: Para permitir el `0` como valor inicial, debes **forzar** al SGBD para que acepte este requerimiento, el cual, dicho sea de paso, es contrario al estándar y no recomendado. Esto se haría ejecutando `SET GLOBAL sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'` o `SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'`. Antes de cambiar esta configuración [revisa lo que dice el MR al respecto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero) y revisa también [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1142472/5587982).